# Huge transactions in the last minute before the end of day after persistent downward pressure on stock

Tags: day-trading, trading-volume, online

I've noticed many times a phenomenon of downward pressure on a stock for half an hour or more before the closing bell and a huge purchase in the last minute at a resulting very low price.  I find it hard to believe the block of 400,000 shares trade was a mystery or surprise although it never appeared on level two. Other than an unexplained downward trend, how can I see this coming? By what mechanism would a market maker accumulate sufficient stock to favor such a trade?

Comment: There's a similar post on this very same question with a good answer. Take a look: [Why there's always a huge volume of trades for AAPL every day before market close?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/39953/why-theres-always-a-very-huge-volume-of-trades-for-aapl-every-day-before-market?rq=1)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why there's always a very huge volume of trades for AAPL every day before market close?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/39953/why-theres-always-a-very-huge-volume-of-trades-for-aapl-every-day-before-market)